# JRE update strategy security advice

Tags: java, security, web-applications, updates

recently I was researching for common vulnerabilities for a particular version of JRE (1.8.0_151) we still have in use and stumbled over cvedetails.com. The result was pretty confusing, since there seems to be no known CVE for this particular version at all. At least, the page does not list this version. However, the page lists results for all kind of newer JRE versions. This  could lead to the (probably false) assumption that version 8.0_151 is more secure as the following newer JRE releases and that there wouldn't be the need to update.
[List of all CVEs for JRE on cvedetails.com](https://www.cvedetails.com/version-search.php?vendor=Oracle&product=JRE&version=1.8.0)

Does someone know why the particular version isn't listed or if it perhaps counts together with version 152?

Additionally, what would be your recommended update strategy approaches for JRE respective security. Is there any best practices? I am aware that it is a matter of time and money to invest in regards of testing compatibility with the application to use with, but apart from this, it would be great to be aware of the best reasons to stay up to date with JRE.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assume that the vulnerability exists not just in the specified update, but also in all prior updates of the given JRE version.  So if the alert calls out 1.8.0_151, you should assume that the issue exists in 1.8.0_*anything-equal-to-or-less-than-151*.

This isn't just because it's better to err on the side of caution.  It's because that's almost always the actual reality of the situation.

There are a couple of reasons why that CVEDetails summary page is incomplete in the sense of not listing every affected update.  The first is that Oracle changed the format of its CVE notices back in 2014.  The earlier format was something like this:

- [Unspecified vulnerability in Oracle Java SE 7u40 and earlier, Java SE 6u60 and earlier, and Java SE Embedded 7u40 and earlier ...](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2013-5852)

which makes it clear that the vulnerability does not exist only in 1.7.0_40, 1.6.0_60 and Embedded 1.7.0_40.  The fact the the vulnerability exists in earlier updates is true for practically every vulnerability, not just in Java but in any software.  The only time that's not the case is when a vulnerability was introduced in an update, and thankfully that's pretty rare.

Oracle's newer format is something like this:

- [Unspecified vulnerability in Oracle Java SE 7u45 and Java SE Embedded 7u45, and OpenJDK 7 ...](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2013-5893)

which no longer makes any statement about the existence of the issue in earlier updates.  Oracle would probably say that they do this because the earlier updates are no longer supported and therefore there's no point in even investigating whether they're vulnerable or not.

In fact Oracle's current format makes that position explicit:

- [Vulnerability in the Java SE, Java SE Embedded product of Oracle Java SE (component: Networking). Supported versions that are affected are Java SE: 7u241 and 8u231; Java SE Embedded: 8u231.](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-2659)

Only the currently-supported versions are specified as being affected.  But the odds are overwhelming that the issue exists in earlier updates too.

The second issue is that even when the original alert format specified "update NNN and earlier", that "and earlier" part is not reflected in the CVEDetails summaries.  For example, the CVEDetails summary for JRE 1.7.0 shows no vulnerabilities for 1.7.0_39, 1.7.0_38, 1.7.0_37, ... even though those were all affected by the "7u40 and earlier" issue in the example of the original alert format I showed above.

> Additionally, what would be your recommended update strategy
>   approaches for JRE respective security. Is there any best practices?

Opinions vary, and opinions are off-topic for StackOverflow.  But IMO, whenever a new update comes out (even if it has no security fixes) you should revalidate your app against the new JRE, so you know in advance whether there's going to be trouble when your customers apply that JRE update.  If there are incompatibilities then you should resolve those ASAP.

If the vulnerability is severe and is exploitable in your app then you should let your customers know that they should apply the JRE update, perhaps after they've first installed a new update of your app if you found incompatibilities when you revalidated.  If the vulnerability is mild and/or not exploitable in your app then you should let your customers know that, let them know if the JRE update requires an app update, and let them decide whether to move to the updated JRE.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain! Just to improve for next time: Why did so many people downvote this question?

Comment: I don't know why they downvoted, and they didn't bother to explain in comments.  My guess is either that they thought this was an end-user or sysadmin question (therefore better asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)) or they thought it was a subjective opinion question based on the "best practices" request.  However, nobody voted to close the question as off-topic, so none of the high-experience readers thought it was too far off the mark for SO.